# Cassandra PER PARTITION LIMIT not working throwing error in dev center

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am trying to run below CQL query in dev center (1.6) and seeing this error thus not allowing me to execute query. I verified DataStax documentation and I see syntax is correct. Any help please?

```
select * from some_table PER PARTITION LIMIT 1;
```

Error I see -> `no viable alternative at input 'PER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using DataStax Enterprise 6.x, then you need to use [DataStax Studio](https://downloads.datastax.com/#studio) instead of DevCenter. DSE 6 supports per partition limit without problems, it's a DevCenter that doesn't understand this syntax.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Per my investigation I too see that DevCenter doesn't work and to use DataStax Studio.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using a version of Cassandra that does not support that syntax.

Comment: I have Cassandra 6.x..is the issue related to dev center tool 1.6?

Comment: could you confirm the version of Cassandra you are using? Cassandra  3.11.5 is the latest version recommended for production as of today

Comment: OP has what sounds like a DSE version number

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas Yes, the version I have listed is for DSE (Datastax Enterprise).

Comment: dev center is an older application that I don't think DataStax supports any longer. The PER PARTITION syntax was a recent addition to CQL so it probably just doesnt understand but DSE6 should work with it.